# Powershell - Deleting certificate from Store

Tags: powershell, certificate

I want to delete testcertificate from the Personal folder under my Computer account. I want to do this by Issued by field. Not the name of the certificate.
This is what i got so far:

```
  $issuername = "domain-Issuing-CA"
  get-item cert:\\LocalMachine\\My\\* | foreach { if($_.issuer.Contains($issuername)) { remove-item $_ }}
```

So basicly what i thought would happen, is look under the localmachine account under storename My (which is Personal) and then go through each certificate if issuer contains my set value on top.

But its not finding it, but i am really not sure if issuer.Contains is enough either, i have this working in C# but im new to Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

`contains` runs against arrays, not strings try this instead :

```
cd Cert:\LocalMachine\My 
ls | ?{$_.issuer -match $issuername}
```